# After verifying email, isEmailVerified is return false in first time of call and in the second time of call is returning true

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, email-verification

Following is the code of button. email is send successfully.

When I verify the email by clicking the link in it and after when I click on the button `user.isEmailVerified` returns `false` for the first time.

But when I press the button the second time `user.isEmailVerified` returns `true`. Why is it not returning `true` in the first attempt?

```java
public void signin(View view)
{
    firstName = firstNameET.getText().toString();
    lastName = lastNameET.getText().toString();
    yearOfBirth = yearOfBirthET.getText().toString();
    contact = contactET.getText().toString();
    city = cityET.getText().toString();
    pincode = pincodeET.getText().toString();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    user.reload();
    if(user.isEmailVerified())
    {
        Log.i("Email","Email is verified.");
        if(!(TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName)
                && TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName)
                && TextUtils.isEmpty(yearOfBirth)
                && TextUtils.isEmpty(contact)
                && TextUtils.isEmpty(city)
                && TextUtils.isEmpty(pincode)))
        {
            if(contact.length() == 10)
            {
                progressDialog.show();
                final DatabaseReference mChild = databaseReference.child("Users").child(user.getUid());
                mChild.child("First Name").setValue(firstName);
                mChild.child("Last Name").setValue(lastName);
                mChild.child("Year of birth").setValue(yearOfBirth);
                if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Male")
                {
                    mChild.child("Gender").setValue("Male");
                }
                else
                {
                    mChild.child("Gender").setValue("Female");
                }
                mChild.child("Contact").setValue(contact);
                mChild.child("City").setValue(city);
                mChild.child("Pincode").setValue(pincode);

                if(imageUri != null)
                {
                    final StorageReference mStorageReference = storageReference.child("Profile Picture").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
                    mStorageReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            mStorageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    mChild.child("Profile Picture").setValue(uri.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter valid contact number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Email","not verified");

        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything in code, it can be Firebase side error, bcz after verifying in mail, or reset mail, emailverify is turn true in firebase, it could be a firebase side Error.

Or code can change according to Firebase auth version.

Update Firebase Auth gradle version. And check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth). Use the code which will work with you..